# Row and Column Search In TicTacToe Game Java

Tags: java, arrays, tic-tac-toe, columnsorting

when running my code it doesn't do a column stop properly, like it doesn't seem to detect that the other player has put 2 in a column and just needs 1 more to win, so it places it's move randomly. The code is below:
//STOP PLAYER 1 FROM WINNING

```
//Check the Rows
counterRow=0;
for(i=0; i<=2; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<=2; j++)
    {
        if (GameBoard[i][j]!= opponent)
        {
            PotentialRow=i;
            PotentialCol=j;
        }
        else
            counterRow++;
    }
    if (counterRow==2)
    {
        UpdateGameBoard(PotentialRow, PotentialCol, playerTwo);
        return;
    }
}
//Check the Columns
counterCol=0;
PotentialRow= -1;
PotentialCol= -1;
for(i=0; i<=2; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<=2; j++)
    {
        if (GameBoard[i][j] != opponent)
        {
            PotentialRow=j;
            PotentialCol=i;
        }
        else
            counterCol++;
    }
    if(counterCol==2)
    {
        UpdateGameBoard(PotentialRow, PotentialCol, playerTwo);
        return;
    }
}
```

My Entire computers turn method is this:

```
public static void ComputerTurn(int playerTwo)
{
    System.out.println("Computers Turn");
    int counterRow= 0;
    int counterCol= 0;
    int PotentialRow= -1;
    int PotentialCol= -1;
    int i,j;
    int opponent=1;

    //Check the Rows if comp already made a move there make another one
    for (i=0; i<=2; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<=2; j++)
        {
            if (GameBoard[i][j]!= opponent)
            {
                PotentialRow=i;
                PotentialCol=j;
            }
            else
                counterRow++;
        }
        if (counterRow==2 && GameBoard[PotentialRow][PotentialCol] != playerTwo)
        {
            UpdateGameBoard(PotentialRow,PotentialCol, playerTwo);
            return;
        }
    }
    //Check the Columns if comp already made a move there make another one
    PotentialRow=-1;
    PotentialCol=-1;

    for (i=0; i<=2; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<=2; j++)
        {
            if (GameBoard[j][i] != opponent)
            {
                PotentialRow=j;
                PotentialCol=i;
            }
            else
                counterCol++;
        }
        if (counterCol==2 && GameBoard[PotentialRow][PotentialCol] != playerTwo)
        {
            UpdateGameBoard(PotentialRow, PotentialCol, playerTwo);
            return;
        }
    }

    //Left Diagonal
    int leftDiagonal=0;
    if (GameBoard[0][0]==opponent)
        leftDiagonal++;
    else
    {
        PotentialRow=0;
        PotentialCol=0;
    }
    if(GameBoard[1][1]==opponent)
        leftDiagonal++;
    else
    {
        PotentialRow=1;
        PotentialCol=1;
    }
    if (GameBoard[2][2]== opponent)
        leftDiagonal++;
    else
    {
        PotentialRow=2;
        PotentialCol=2;
    }
    if (leftDiagonal==2 && GameBoard[PotentialRow][PotentialCol] != playerTwo && GameBoard[PotentialRow][PotentialCol] != opponent)
    {
        UpdateGameBoard(PotentialRow, PotentialCol, playerTwo);
        return;
    }

    //Right Diagonal
    int rightDiagonal=0;
    if (GameBoard[2][0]==opponent)
        rightDiagonal++;
    else
    {
        PotentialRow=2;
        PotentialCol=0;
    }
    if(GameBoard[1][1]==opponent)
        rightDiagonal++;
    else
    {
        PotentialRow=1;
        PotentialCol=1;
    }
    if (GameBoard[0][2]== opponent)
        rightDiagonal++;
    else
    {
        PotentialRow=0;
        PotentialCol=2;
    }
    if (rightDiagonal==2 && GameBoard[PotentialRow][PotentialCol] != playerTwo && GameBoard[PotentialRow][PotentialCol] != opponent)
    {
        UpdateGameBoard(PotentialRow, PotentialCol, playerTwo);
        return;
    }

    //STOP PLAYER 1 FROM WINNING

    //Check the Rows
    for (i=0; i<=2; i++)
    {
        counterRow=0;
        for(j=0; j<=2; j++)
        {
            if (GameBoard[i][j]!= opponent)
            {
                PotentialRow=i;
                PotentialCol=j;
            }
            else
                counterRow++;
        }
        if (counterRow==2)
        {
            UpdateGameBoard(PotentialRow, PotentialCol, playerTwo);
            return;
        }
    }
    //Check the Columns
    for(i=0; i<=2; i++)
    {
        counterCol=0;
        for(j=0; j<=2; j++)
        {
            if (GameBoard[j][i] != opponent)
            {
                PotentialRow=j;
                PotentialCol=i;
            }
            else
                counterCol++;
        }
        if(counterCol==2)
        {
            UpdateGameBoard(PotentialRow, PotentialCol, playerTwo);
            return;
        }
    }
    //Check the Right Diagonal
    rightDiagonal=0;
    if (GameBoard[2][0]==opponent)
        rightDiagonal++;
    else
    {
        PotentialRow=2;
        PotentialCol=0;
    }
    if(GameBoard[1][1]==opponent)
        rightDiagonal++;
    else
    {
        PotentialRow=1;
        PotentialCol=1;
    }
    if (GameBoard[0][2]== opponent)
        rightDiagonal++;
    else
    {
        PotentialRow=0;
        PotentialCol=2;
    }
    if (rightDiagonal==2)
    {
        UpdateGameBoard(PotentialRow, PotentialCol, playerTwo);
        return;
    }

    //If none of the above applies, then make a random move
    for(i=0; i<=2; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<=2; j++)
        {
            if (GameBoard[i][j] != playerTwo && GameBoard[i][j] != opponent)
            {
                UpdateGameBoard(i,j,playerTwo);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Computer Finished Turn");
}
```

Comment: Don't delete your question content, use comments instead.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to reset the counter for each row.
So instead of this:

> ```
> counterRow=0;
> for(i=0; i<=2; i++)
> {
>     for(j=0; j<=2; j++)
> ```

Do like this:

```
for(i=0; i<=2; i++)
{
    int counterRow = 0;
    for(j=0; j<=2; j++)
```

You'll need to do similarly for columns.

Next, when checking the columns,
instead of `GameBoard[i][j] != opponent`, you need to flip the `i` and `j`:
`GameBoard[j][i] != opponent`, otherwise it's not really checking the columns, but the rows again.

Lastly, note that you're not checking diagonals.

As a side note, these lines are pointless and can be removed:

> ```
> PotentialRow= -1;
> PotentialCol= -1;
> ```

---

With the above suggestions applied, here's the modified code:

```
            //Check the Rows
            for(i=0; i<=2; i++)
            {
                int counterRow=0;
                for(j=0; j<=2; j++)
                {
                    if (GameBoard[i][j]!= opponent)
                    {
                        PotentialRow=i;
                        PotentialCol=j;
                    }
                    else
                        counterRow++;
                }
                if (counterRow==2)
                {
                    UpdateGameBoard(PotentialRow, PotentialCol, playerTwo);
                    return;
                }
            }
            //Check the Columns
            for(i=0; i<=2; i++)
            {
                int counterCol=0;
                for(j=0; j<=2; j++)
                {
                    if (GameBoard[j][i] != opponent)
                    {
                        PotentialRow=j;
                        PotentialCol=i;
                    }
                    else
                        counterCol++;
                }
                if(counterCol==2)
                {
                    UpdateGameBoard(PotentialRow, PotentialCol, playerTwo);
                    return;
                }
            }
```

Comment: @JaneDoe I added the code with my modifications. If it still doesn't work then maybe you have another problem somewhere else

Comment: do you know where possibly? I don't see how something else could affect it checking the columns?

Comment: I edited my post and added the entire computer method.